# Remove unwanted space from url

Tags: php, url, pagination, space

Im using php  pagination function

the function is

```
/**
 * Displays pagination links based on given parameters
 *
 * @param int $currentPage - current page
 * @param int $itemCount - number of items to paginate, used to calculate total number of pages
 * @param int $itemsPerPage - number of items per page, used to calculate total number of pages
 * @param int $adjacentCount - half the number of page links displayed adjacent to the current page
 * @param (string|callable) $pageLinkTemplate - pagination URL string containing %d placeholder or a callable function that accepts page number and returns page URL
 * @param boolean $showPrevNext - whether to show previous and next page links
 * @return void
 */
function pagination($currentPage, $itemCount, $itemsPerPage, $adjacentCount, $pageLinkTemplate, $showPrevNext = true) {
    $firstPage = 1;

    $lastPage  = ceil($itemCount / $itemsPerPage);
    if ($lastPage == 1) {
        return;
    }
    if ($currentPage <= $adjacentCount -     $adjacentCount) {
        $firstAdjacentPage = $firstPage;
        $lastAdjacentPage  = min($firstPage + $adjacentCount + $adjacentCount, $lastPage);
    } elseif ($currentPage > $lastPage - $adjacentCount - $adjacentCount) {
        $lastAdjacentPage  = $lastPage;
        $firstAdjacentPage = $lastPage - $adjacentCount - $adjacentCount;
    } else {
        $firstAdjacentPage = $currentPage - $adjacentCount;
        $lastAdjacentPage  = $currentPage + $adjacentCount;
    }
    echo '<div>';
    if ($showPrevNext) {
        if ($currentPage == $firstPage - 1) {
            echo '<li><span class="1 searchPaginationPrev list-first">&lt;</span></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a class="2 searchPaginationPrev list-first" href="' . (is_callable($pageLinkTemplate) ? $pageLinkTemplate($currentPage - 1) : sprintf($pageLinkTemplate, $currentPage - 1)) . '">&lt;</a></li>';
        }
    }
    if ($firstAdjacentPage > $firstPage) {
        echo '<li><a class="3 searchPaginationNonSelected" href="' . (is_callable($pageLinkTemplate) ? $pageLinkTemplate($firstPage) : sprintf($pageLinkTemplate, $firstPage)) . '">' . $firstPage . '</a></li>';
        if ($firstAdjacentPage > $firstPage + 1) {
            echo '<li><span class="1">...</span></li>';
        }
    }
    for ($i = $firstAdjacentPage; $i <= $lastAdjacentPage; $i++) {
        if ($currentPage == $i - 1) {
            echo '<li><span class="4 searchPaginationSelected">' . $i . '</span></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a class="5 searchPaginationNonSelected" href="'. (is_callable($pageLinkTemplate) ? $pageLinkTemplate($i - 1) : sprintf($pageLinkTemplate, $i - 1)).'">' . $i . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    if ($lastAdjacentPage < $lastPage) {
        if ($lastAdjacentPage < $lastPage - 1) {
            echo '<li><span class="2">...</span></li>';
        }
        echo '<li><a class="6 searchPaginationNonSelected" href="' . (is_callable($pageLinkTemplate) ? $pageLinkTemplate($lastPage) : sprintf($pageLinkTemplate, $lastPage - 1)) . '">' . $lastPage . '</a></li>';
    }
    if ($showPrevNext) {
        if ($currentPage == $lastPage) {
            echo '<li><span class="7 searchPaginationNext list-last">&gt;</span></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a class="8 searchPaginationNext list-last" href="' . (is_callable($pageLinkTemplate) ? $pageLinkTemplate($currentPage + 1) : sprintf($pageLinkTemplate, $currentPage + 1)) . '">&gt;</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and i echo the function like

```
pagination(Params::getParam('iPage'), $iTotalItems, $itemsPerPage, 2, osc_update_search_url(array('iPage'=>%d)));
```

its working well but i got some spaces on url.. how to remove the space.. i also tried with str_replace, preg_replace but no use.. can anyone help me please..

[screnshot of url image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLn8D.jpg)

the function i got form [here](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/04/stackoverflow-like-pagination.html)

Comment: Show sample URL where you got spaces

Comment: i added the screen shot http://i.stack.imgur.com/rLn8D.jpg

Comment: So you get a value with spaces in front of it? Like `____3`? if that's the case, did you try something like `$new_value = intval( $old_value, 10);`? Or a normal `trim()`?

Comment: What does `osc_update_search_url` function return to you?
When I call `pagination(10, 100, 8, 2, "page/%d");` there're no extra spaces, so I assume you give it wrong template.

Comment: osc_search_url() function is return a web path(mysite.com/search) and inside the array is become param
ex mysite.com/search/iPage,2

Comment: i think %d is a problem, can i change the %d as a varaible?